# How make hadoop mapper output to be processed by its own reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapper

Now, when a hadoop mapper output some blocks, it will be transferred to a new node where a reducer is running. Even though the node which runs the mapper, also run the reducer it is not guaranteed that its output blocks will be processed by the same local reducer.

But I need to make it work like that. What I need is make it guarantee that the blocks created with mapper output is processed only by the reducer running in the same node.

Please help to give me some tips.

Comment: What if different mappers, running on different nodes, produce records with the same key?  Those records need to be fed to the same reducer even though they came from different nodes.

Comment: @Wyzard is absolutely correct! If you need this kind of functionality, make sure that MapReduce is the right choice for you.